# Raw query convert to Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Need help in converting this query to eloquent for me to use the paginate, groupby and orderby method

```
                SELECT
                DATE(created_at),
                SUM(CASE WHEN `type` = 'withdraw' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'withdraw_count',
                SUM(CASE WHEN `type` = 'withdraw' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS 'withdraw_amount',
                SUM(CASE WHEN `type` = 'deposit' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'deposit_count',
                SUM(CASE WHEN `type` = 'deposit' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS 'deposit_amount'
            FROM
            (
                SELECT created_at, 'withdraw' as `type`, amount FROM withdraw
                UNION ALL
                SELECT created_at, 'deposit' as `type`, amount FROM deposit
            ) t
            GROUP by DATE(created_at)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
$from = DB::table('withdraw')
    ->select('created_at', DB::raw("'withdraw' as `type`"), 'amount')
    ->unionAll(
        DB::table('deposit')
            ->select('created_at', DB::raw("'deposit' as `type`"), 'amount')
    );
DB::query()
    ->selectRaw('DATE(created_at)')
    ->selectRaw("SUM(CASE WHEN `type` = 'withdraw' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'withdraw_count'")
    ->selectRaw("SUM(CASE WHEN `type` = 'withdraw' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS 'withdraw_amount'")
    ->selectRaw("SUM(CASE WHEN `type` = 'deposit' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'deposit_count'")
    ->selectRaw("SUM(CASE WHEN `type` = 'deposit' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS 'deposit_amount'")
    ->fromSub($from, 't')
    ->groupBy(DB::raw('DATE(created_at)'))
    ->get();
```